# "Read past end of file" on lookup jms/RemoteConnectionFactory on wildfly

Tags: java, jms, wildfly

I'm trying to do basic a JMS operation using WildFly 26.1.1. I have simple method to lookup `jms/RemoteConnectionFactory`:

```java
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://localhost:8080");
InitialContext ic=new InitialContext(properties);
ConnectionFactory f = (ConnectionFactory) ic.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory") ;
```

Unfortunately I'm still receiving this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.CommunicationException: WFNAM00020: Remote naming operation failed [Root exception is java.io.EOFException: Read past end of file]
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteClientTransport.lookup(RemoteClientTransport.java:289)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteContext.lambda$lookupNative$0(RemoteContext.java:190)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.NamingProvider.performExceptionAction(NamingProvider.java:222)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteContext.performWithRetry(RemoteContext.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteContext.lookupNative(RemoteContext.java:188)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.AbstractFederatingContext.lookup(AbstractFederatingContext.java:74)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.store.RelativeFederatingContext.lookupNative(RelativeFederatingContext.java:58)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.AbstractFederatingContext.lookup(AbstractFederatingContext.java:74)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.AbstractFederatingContext.lookup(AbstractFederatingContext.java:60)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.AbstractFederatingContext.lookup(AbstractFederatingContext.java:66)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyRootContext.lookup(WildFlyRootContext.java:144)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at first.jms.WildflyJms.sendMessage(WildflyJms.java:17)
    at first.jms.WildflyJms.main(WildflyJms.java:9)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Read past end of file
    at org.jboss.marshalling.SimpleDataInput.eofOnRead(SimpleDataInput.java:151)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.SimpleDataInput.readUnsignedByteDirect(SimpleDataInput.java:294)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.SimpleDataInput.readUnsignedByte(SimpleDataInput.java:249)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockUnmarshaller.readUnsignedByte(BlockUnmarshaller.java:258)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockUnmarshaller.readInt(BlockUnmarshaller.java:296)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockUnmarshaller.readUTF(BlockUnmarshaller.java:326)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.readExternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:200)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1444)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:298)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:231)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteClientTransport.lookup(RemoteClientTransport.java:271)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: an exception which occurred:
    in object of type org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory
```

Comment: Can you paste the configuration of `jms/RemoteConnectionFactory` from your server config?

Comment: This is essentially the same code as found in [this WildFly quickstart](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/blob/main/helloworld-jms/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/quickstarts/jms/HelloWorldJMSClient.java) so I would expect it to work.

Comment: I ran the aforementioned quickstart and the connection factory lookup worked fine. You must have something non-standard going on with your configuration or environment.

Comment: I haven't changed anything in default wildfly configuration, that's why it is so mysterious for me. I was trying the same code on wildfly 25.0, and have the same error. My build gradle is also very simple and contains mainly dependency: 
dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/jboss-client.jar')
}

jboss-client.jar was copied from wildfly. 
I'm using jdk8. Maybe this is causing the problem. Will have to check

Comment: I just ran with JDK 8 and there were no problems.

Comment: I have checked this code on other PC and it works. Now I will struggle what is the difference between those two PCes

Comment: Did you get this sorted? If so, what was the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what causes this problem. I just moved with my work to second PC, where everything works